# Making the Readers/Writer threads go R/W/R/W

Tags: java, synchronization

I got an homework where I have to implement a Generator thread (Writer) which sends a sequence of number starting from 0 to N Avg threads (Readers) such that 0 goes to Avg_0, 1 to Avg_1 and N goes again to Avg_0 and so on. Once the Avg threads receive M numbers they calculate the average of them and send it in output.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/jsr9Nn3i) u can see my code where I used the Monitor class as a database where the threads can write on and read from safely

Now, everything is running smoothly but you can see I used two Thread.sleep() to make sure the Readers/Writer work in this order W/R/W/R/W..., otherwise I'd always see the Generator write multiple times on the database before the Avgs are able to read or the Avgs print multiple times before the Generator can send new numbers.

What I'm asking is: how can I implement a lock with synchronized methods so that I don't have to use the sleep methods?

Comment: Too broad: there are many ways to do this

Comment: can you give me some of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it where the Monitor holds at most N values, the average is calculated in the Avg class, and the Generator just sends a stream of numbers to the Monitor. The sleep is not needed, but I have kept one so that we can read the output.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N=2;
        int M=3;

        Monitor m = new Monitor(N);

        Generator g = new Generator(m);
        g.start();

        Avg[] avg = new Avg[N];
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
            avg[i]=new Avg(i, m, M);
            avg[i].start();
        }
    }
}

class Generator extends Thread {
    private final Monitor m;

    public Generator(Monitor m) {
        this.m = m;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i= 0;
        try {
            do {
                m.doWrite(i);
                ++i;
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } while (true);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }
    }
}

class Avg extends Thread {
    private final int id;
    private final Monitor m;
    private final int M;

    public Avg(int id, Monitor m, int M) {
        this.id = id;
        this.m = m;
        this.M = M;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            do {
                double sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
                    sum += m.doRead(id);
                }
                double avg = sum / M;
                System.out.println("Avg " + id + " : " + avg);
            } while (true);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }
    }
}

class Monitor { 
    private final Integer[] numbers;
    private int current;

    public Monitor(int N) {
        numbers = new Integer[N];
    }

    public synchronized void doWrite(int i) throws InterruptedException{
        while (numbers[current] != null) {
            wait();
        }
        numbers[current]=i;
        current = (current+1)%numbers.length;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized int doRead(int id) throws InterruptedException{                
        while (numbers[id] == null) {
            wait();
        }
        int result = numbers[id];
        numbers[id] = null;
        notifyAll();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, wasn't expecting such a complete answer, thank you very much! 
Could you tell me though why a sleep is needed? i tried commenting it and the program gives no output at all

Comment: @petrogass sorry, I made a mistake: I forgot the notifyAll in doRead. It's now corrected.

Comment: should i initialize current to 0 or it isn't necessary?

Comment: @petrogass it is set to 0 by default